# HackerRank: Encryption

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

Given a two-dimensional list, say `some_list = ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJ"]`, I am supposed to encrypt it by reading each column top to bottom, thus:

> ```
> A B C D
>
> E F G H
>
> I J
> ```

Would become:

> ```
> AEI BFJ CG DH
> ```

My initial try had “index out of range” problem so I did this:

> ```
> def encrypt_list(some_list):
>     encrpted_list = []
>     for i in range(c):
>         string = ""
>         for j in range(f):
>             string += my_list[j][i:i + 1]
>         encrpted_list.append(string)
>     return encrpted_list
> ```

Which looks like a hack. Is there a more Pythonic way?

(This is essentially the [Encryption](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption) problem from HackerRank.)

Complete working code:

```
import math

s = "feedthedog"
length_s = len(s)

f = math.floor(math.sqrt(length_s))
c = math.ceil(math.sqrt(length_s))

if c * f < length_s:
    f = c


def chunks(string, split_point):
    for start in range(0, len(string), split_point):
        yield s[start:start + split_point]


split_list = [chunk for chunk in chunks(s, c)]


def encrypt_list(my_list):
    encrpted_list = []
    for i in range(c):
        string = ""
        for j in range(f):
            string += my_list[j][i:i + 1]
        encrpted_list.append(string)
    return encrpted_list


solution_list = encrypt_list(split_list)


for item in solution_list:
    print(item, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There's an app for that**

The nice thing about the python standard library, especially [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) is that there's always a function for what you want to do. In this case, you want to take chunks like:

```
['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJ']
```

and turn them into chunks like:

```
['AEI', 'BFJ', 'CG', 'DH']
```

That is, we're round robining through each row. There's a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for that:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

So ultimately, we have just a couple steps:

1. Get our [`chunks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/2069064).
2. Round robin through them.
3. Join the result

   ```
   def chunks(l, n):
       """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
       for i in range(0, len(l), n):
           yield l[i:i+n]

   def encrypt(s):
       n = int(math.sqrt(len(s))
       chunked = chunks(s, n)
       return ''.join(roundrobin(*chunked))
   ```

**Prefer to `join`**

In your solution, you have:

```
string = ""
for j in range(f):
    string += my_list[j][i:i + 1]
encrpted_list.append(string)
```

This is inefficient though. When we're building up strings, it's much better to `join` them:

```
encrpted_list.append(''.join(my_list[j][i:i+1] for j in range(f)))
```

**Evaluate lazily**

This is inefficient:

```
split_list = [chunk for chunk in chunks(s, c)]
```

You likely only evaluated out `chunks` due to the way you wrote your encrypter, but you want to keep things as generators for as long as possible. It's more efficient to pass in `chunks(s,c)` into the `zip_longest()` than it would be to fully evaluate it. Though if you do, it's shorter to just write:

```
split_list = list(chunks(s,c))
```

**Minor points**

1. Excessive amounts of vertical spacing here.
2. `encrpted_list` is misspelled: should be `encrypted_list`.
3. Why do you have `encrypt_list` that takes a `list` and returns a `list`? You should have `encrypt` that takes a string and returns a string.
4. You don't need `f`,`c`... you can use `int` to get the floor, and add 1 if necessary. And avoid single-letter names.

Comment: Minor point (1): I think your solution have it all as one string; it has to be separated by a single space. Minor point (2): I think your code assumes the new matrix as complete.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Barry that `itertools` is your friend here.  However, I would note that transposing matrices is often done using some kind of `zip()` function.  Here, I would use `itertools.zip_longest()`, since it's not a complete rectangle.

```
[''.join(filter(None, col)) for col in itertools.zip_longest(*some_list)]
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Convert tuples to strings            Transpose matrix
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I started with, but then I thought we needed to join everything back together at the end too so I went with `roundrobin`. Also, you can pass in a fillvalue for `zip_longest` to avoid the filter.

Comment: You could also just use an outer `" ".join` if you need to return a string rather than a list

Answer (score 3):

Another approach you could take is to *pad the string with empty characters*. These characters have no effect on the result. But they help you avoid "index out of range" problem and no need to use if-else for the boundary checks.

Moreover, we do not need to split the string into chunks. Instead, we could pick out values from the padded string using strides with step = `n_cols`.

Here's the full implementation:

```
def encrypt(s):
    L = len(s)
    n_cols = int(ceil(sqrt(L)))
    n_rows = (L + n_cols - 1) // n_cols
    s_padded = list(s) + [''] * (n_rows * n_cols - L)
    out = []

    for c in range(n_cols):
        out += s_padded[c::n_cols]
        out.append(' ')
    return ''.join(out[:-1])
```